# Python - Function in separated file not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

in the last days I learned a little bit Python. Now I've tried to make a GUI with PyQT and I wanted to write the program with the functions in a second file called untitled2. In this file is a function to check if a number oder something different was inserted in the textedit. When I insert this function in the main file, this program works. But when I make it in a second file (untitled2) and I insert this file, this program doesn't work anymore. A absolutely have no idea why...

Here is the small example without the gui program-code.

Main file:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from untitled1 import *


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = loadUi('testprogramgui.ui')


w.Button_button_1.clicked.connect(check)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the file untitled2 with the function:

```
def check():

    try:
        insert= w.insertValue1.text()
        insert2= float(insert)
        #check to control
        print(insert2, type(insert2))

    except:
        print("no number")
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem? I think you don't need the gui-file, so I didn't wrote it here.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module must be independent of another module, each function must also be independent, so in your case the "check" function should not take into account the source of the information in the text for this we make the "check" function receive the information:

```py
# ...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = loadUi('testprogramgui.ui')

def on_clicked():
    check(w.insertValue1.text())

w.Button_button_1.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
def check(insert):
    try:
        insert2= float(insert)
        #check to control
        print(insert2, type(insert2))

    except:
        print("no number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to import the "untitled2" file? Now your code is showing that you are importing "untitled1"?

`from untitled1 import *` gets `from untitled2 import *`